# How to create a float64x2_t type for raspberry?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, arm, neon

I want to convert my codes from Intel architecture to Raspbain. So "arm_neon.h" is the best choice to do this. I used **__m128d** which is same as **float64x2_t**, and a lot of Intel Intrinsics like "_mm_sub_sd". These can be easily written by "arch64/arm_neon.h" cause it has **float64x2_t** type with Intrinsics like "vsubq_f64". But "arm_neon.h" under raspberry doesn't contain this type. So what should I do if I wanna use this.

Comment: Then what type *do* the header file have defined? What is the type it uses for e.g. `vsubq_f64`?

Comment: I would guess that it's something like this: `double f64x2[2];`

Comment: there is [raspberry/arm_neon.h](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/blob/master/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/include/arm_neon.h) , and [arch64/arm_neon.h](https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/gcc/+/32fce3edda831e36ee484406c39dffbe0230f257/gcc-4.8/gcc/config/aarch64/arm_neon.h) . You can see "raspberry/arm_neon.h" doesn't have a **float64x2_t** type. And my codes are all built by **__m128d** which need a **float64x2_t** as substitute. `vsubq_f64` is defined as `float64x2_t vsubq_f64 (float64x2_t __a, float64x2_t __b)` to substitute

Comment: `__m128d _mm_sub_sd (__m128d a, __m128d b) `

Comment: @JL2210 Thank you. I'll try this if I cannot find a better one.

Comment: `aarch32` NEON doesn't support `double` at all, one of the reasons 32bit NEON isn't IEEE754 compliant. You will have to stick to `aarch64` should you insist on `double`.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE So I have to change all my codes from `__m128d` to `__m128`. Thank you.

Comment: @zen I'd rather ditch `aarch32` altogether and make it 64bit-only.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE There is a project urges me to use `aarch32`.

Comment: @zen In addition, v7a NEON isn't capable of fused multiply accumulate on `float`, and thus, subnormal numbers will be way less accurate than on x86. And NEON isn't exactly nimble dealing with `float`. You better should consider fixed-point math instead.